# How to check an app is installed on a specific phone

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application for android users, and I wondered if there is a way to check if my application is installed on another phone without the help of a server.
I will explain it more clearly - I want to be able to choose from my phone contacts, the people to chat with, but I need to filter only the contacts who has my application, otherwise it won't work.
Is it posiible? If it is, someone can guide me?

Thanks a lot!

p.s. - **I can't use a server** to save info about users who signed up to the application!

Comment: How are you intending to write a chat application without a server?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to just know what apps someone else has on their phone based on their contact information. That would be strange.

Comment: CommonWare - the chat app I am using is based on google-talk, so I am using their service without a server of my own.
Is it really does not posible?
It's necessary to have a server of my own?